# Linux Kernel Module - Create Directory

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I've got a problem about creating a directory within a linux kernel module.

What I want: Creating a directory within a kernel module.

Here is my actual code:

```
struct file *fp = (struct file *) NULL;
fp = filp_open("/home/testdir", O_DIRECTORY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
```

But it creates a file instead of directory.

I tried to same code as above without the flag "O_DIRECTORY":

```
struct file *fp = (struct file *) NULL;
fp = filp_open("/home/testdir", O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
```

And the result is similar to the previous result.

I don't understand the behaviour. What am I doing wrong?

Edit 1:
I am coding on a Raspberry PI, Raspbian, kernel version: 4.4.43-v7

Comment: Perhaps the `O_DIRECTORY` means to create any parent directories, did you try `"home/testdir/delete-this"`? If it works, then you are using the wrong function. Oh, this is just a wild guess. I have no idea of what `filp_open()` is or does.

Comment: This doesn't work, but thanks for the try! It doesn't create the directories "testdir" or "delete-this"

Comment: Why don't you use `mkdir()`? and this call should fail according to the man don't you check the return value? ["If pathname is not a directory, cause the open to fail."](http://rz2.com/man2/open.2.html). By the way, this is useless to cast `NULL` and this is useless to initialize your variable to `NULL` if you affect it just after. This is bad practice.

Comment: @Stargateur : I use the flag "O_CREAT" to create the directory. man-Page says: "If the file does not exist it will be created.". And thanks for giving the hint for the bad practice!

Comment: @Stargateur : How do I use "mkdir()" in a kernel module? Which includes do I need?

Comment: @DanielChristoph According to the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdir), you must `#include <sys/stat.h>` note that I never did kernel module so I don't know if you can use it.

Answer (score 5):

I got it by myself.
The solution is:

```
struct file *fp = (struct file *) NULL;
fp = filp_open("/home/testdir/", O_DIRECTORY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR);
```

Note the "/" at the end of the path.

Thanks @all for the try!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't create a directory but opens a directory like `opendir` does (the directory should exists).

Comment: So the combination "O_DIRECTORY|O_CREAT" doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly, filp_open works as open does and you canot create dirs with open.

Comment: I got the solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

something that worked for me:
its also similar to how they create a dir in devtmpfs

int mkdir_(const char *dirPath, umode_t mode) {

```
struct path path;
struct dentry *dentry = kern_path_create(AT_FDCWD, dirPath, &path, mode);

int err = PTR_ERR(dentry);
if (IS_ERR(dentry)) {
    return -1;
}

err = vfs_mkdir(path.dentry->d_inode, dentry, mode);
done_path_create(&path, dentry);

return err;
```

}